# Global array showing as empty after adding data in a completion handler (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, completionhandler

What I am trying to achieve is load a UITableView with users after I have retrieved all data from Google Firestore and set it to my global array (self.activeUsers). Inside the closure I am able to see the array properly adding the elements but when I try to use this global variable anywhere else (for instance in the viewDidLoad() method) it shows it as an empty array. I am new to Swift so I know there is something silly I am not understanding here with maybe an async call or completion handling.  There's a lot of code in here I feel like can be ignored since I know the overall issue is my global variable self.activeUsers contains no data in viewDidLoad however, I can see it correctly being set in fetchActiveUsers()

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myCompletionHandler: () -> Void = {
            print("Count in viewDidLoad: ", self.activeUsers.count) // activeUsers count is 0 here. But why?
            self.loadActiveUsersTableView()
        }
        fetchActiveUsers(using: myCompletionHandler)
    }

    func loadActiveUsersTableView() {
        self.view.addSubview(activeUsersTableView)
        self.activeUsersTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [
                self.activeUsersTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 150),
                self.activeUsersTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
                self.activeUsersTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -280),
                self.activeUsersTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -250),
            ]
        )
        self.activeUsersTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func fetchActiveUsers(using completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let myCompletionHandler: (UserProfile?) -> Void = { theUser in
            self.activeUsers.append(theUser!)
            print("Count in fetchActiveUsers myCompletionHandler", self.activeUsers.count) // Able to see this increment correctly after adding a user
        }
        self.chatsDocRef!.getDocument { document, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("Error getting document: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else {
                if let document = document {
                    let data = document.data()
                    self.activeUserUIDS = data?["users"] as? [String]
                    for i in 0..<(self.activeUserUIDS?.count ?? 0) {
                        print("Retrieving document for user ID: ", self.activeUserUIDS![i])
                        let userDocRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(self.activeUserUIDS![i])
                        UserProfile.getUserProfileData(userDocRef, using: myCompletionHandler)
                    }
                    completionHandler()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you are making an asynchronous call inside the callback closure of another asynchronous call, you are not making it easy for yourself. `completionHandler()` is called after the for loop but before any answers has been received from `UserProfile.getUserProfileData` so that is why you are not seeing any values when it gets called.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Where should I be calling completionHandler()?

Comment: I think it's not about moving that call but to restructure your solution. I don't know firebase but is it perhaps possible to merge the two calls to firebase into one, that would be the most efficient solution if it is doable.

Comment: You could put the call to completionHandler into the body of `myCompletionHandler` but then it would be called repeatedly. You will need some logic to only call it after the last iteration of your loop.

Comment: @DuncanC I tried adding the completionHandler into the body of myCompletionHandler and I was finally able to see the users in my table however, it looks like cellForRowAt in the UITableViewDelegate somehow gets called multiple times resulting in a user being completely on top of another user in the same cell

Comment: What does `UserProfile.getUserProfileData(userDocRef, using: myCompletionHandler)` do? Does it make a Firestore call?

Comment: It does, yes.  It retrieves the data document for 1 user and sets it to a modeled UserProfile.  I managed to figure out what I was doing wrong though and will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloading the data inside the completion handler was key to fixing my issue however, I also needed to make a custom design cell class and use prepareForReuse for my UITableView